# Выполнение команд cmd из функции java-script

Tags: javascript, html, cmd

Можно ли запустить cmd команды через функцию java-script одним нажатием кнопки?

cmd команды

```
sqlldr userid=PET/123@O_S-ORACLE control=loadxml.ctl
del d:\load\*.xml
```

HTML

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btnsubgr3" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='cmd()' type="submit">Обновить</button>
      </div>
```

JAVA-SCRIPT

```
    <script>
     function cmd() {
}
     </script>
```

Comment: Что за "cmd команда"? Приведите пример

Comment: Добавил в вопросе

Comment: Возможно, в node.js есть такая возможность

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916184/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-in-nodejs

Comment: bat файл наверно также подойдет для решения задачи.

Comment: Сто процентов, однако все равно придется делать в node.js

Comment: Как node.js использовать в функции java-script?

Comment: "Обычный" JavaScript работает исключительно в браузерной среде. Запускается он на клиенте. Через браузер вы просто не сможете запускать cmd-команды, ибо это нарушает все возможные и невозможные правила конфиденциальности. Node.js - серверный JavaScript. Это самый обыкновенный js, но запускается он в специальной среде - node.js. Там вы можете вытворять все, что душе угодно

Comment: вообще-то можно попытаться вызвать команду через Vbscript из браузера. Но для этого нужен  браузер Internet Explorer и нужно чтобы эта небезопасная опция была активирована в браузере.